# How do I join multiple entries in one table into a single relationship status in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Follow`, which only holds records of which `UserID` follows which `TargetID`.

If asked for user A:

- If neither A or B are following eachother, they have status of `0` for **unrelated**, and aren't included in the results.
- If user A is following B but not vice versa, B has status `1` for
  being **followed**.
- If user B is following A but not vice versa, B has
  status `2` for being a **follower**.
- If A is following B, and B following
  A, B has status of `3` for being a **friend**.

How can I, in a single MySQL query, get the relationship status for a given user and all its relationships above status 0?

Example:

```
Users:
+----+-------+
| id | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Bob   | 
|  2 | Steve |
|  3 | Scott | 
|  4 | Mary  | 
+----+-------+

Follow:
+----+--------+----------+
| id | UserID | TargetID |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |        3 |
|  3 |      2 |        1 |
|  4 |      4 |        1 |
+----+--------+----------+

Expected result for user 1:
+----------+--------+-------+
| TargetID | Status | Name  |
+----------+--------+-------+
|        2 |      3 | Steve | (friend)
|        3 |      1 | Scott | (following)
|        4 |      2 |  Mary | (follower)
+----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you please share the sample data and expected output columns?

Comment: Added example, and user names for readability

Comment: as per sample, I believe that `Steve` should also be the `friend`

Comment: Right you are, should be correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subqueries as illustrated below:

```
-- FOR USER 1
SELECT A.id TargetID,
 SUM(IFNULL((SELECT 1 C FROM Follow B WHERE B.UserID=1 AND B.TargetID=A.id),0) +
     IFNULL((SELECT 2 C FROM Follow D WHERE A.id=D.UserID AND D.TargetID=1), 0)) Status
     , A.name
FROM (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID<>1) A
GROUP BY A.id, A.Name
HAVING Status>0; -- for a compact result

-- NOW GLOBALLY
SELECT A.UserID, A.id TargetID,
 SUM(IFNULL((SELECT 1 C FROM Follow B WHERE B.UserID=A.UserID AND B.TargetID=A.id),0) +
     IFNULL((SELECT 2 C FROM Follow D WHERE A.id=D.UserID AND D.TargetID=A.UserID), 0)) Status
     , A.name
FROM (SELECT E.id UserID, F.* FROM Users E JOIN Users F ON E.id<>F.id) A
GROUP BY A.UserID, A.id, A.Name
HAVING Status>0 -- for a compact result
ORDER BY A.UserID;
```

See [**DEMO on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77d69d/6)

Comment: what's the 'Select 1 C'  and  'id <>' meaning? If you've got the time

Comment: `id <>` means id different from. `Select 1 C` is just a way of returning 1 if the condition in the select is met, I used that to construct the value of the status as per the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and extra for the demo! This works great, except if I add more users which don't have any follow, they show up as a relationship 0, how can these also be excluded in the result? See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4d741/1

Comment: Still isn't working for the first query, try adding a 5th user to the demo with no Follows. It will show up as 0 for the user specific query.

Comment: Copy and paste the query from my answer here to the demo and run.

Comment: I have, it will cull them for the global list, but not the first query, and it doesn't work with moving the HAVING to the top query either. See updated example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4d741/2

Comment: OK I updated it again, I forgot to update the first query before.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but try something among the lines of:

```
Select t.targetid as TargetId, 
    IF (
        (select count(id) from follow where
         follow.Userid = f.target.id and follow.target_id = u.id) > 1, 
         -- mean’s the target is following user 1
         (IF (
            (select count(id) from follow where
            follow.Userid = u.id and follow.target_id = f.targetid) > 1, 3, 2)) 
            -- if user1 is following aswell, then its a friend, else its a follower
         , 1) 
         -- else means its a following
as status, 
u.name as Name from follow f  
inner Join users u on u.id = f.targetid
where u.id = 1
```

1. Inner join to select user 1's relations (if it doesn't exist, they aren't related)
2. If there is a record, means they are one of 3:

Comment: This gives an error: `An alias was previously found. (near "status" at position 401)`